# How to connect to Azure Table Storage using RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-table-storage, rbac

I want to connect to Azure Table Storage using RBAC. I have done the role assignment in the portal but I could not find a way to connect to Azure Table form .NET code. I could find a lot of  documentation on how to connect to BlobClient

```
static void CreateBlobContainer(string accountName, string containerName)
{
    // Construct the blob container endpoint from the arguments.
    string containerEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}",
                                                accountName,
                                                containerName);

    // Get a token credential and create a service client object for the blob container.
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(containerEndpoint),
                                                                  new DefaultAzureCredential());

    // Create the container if it does not exist.
    containerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
}
```

But could not find the similar documentation for Azure Table Acess.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patterns for authorizing with Azure Active Directory and other token sources for the current generation of the Azure SDK are based on credentials from the `Azure.Identity` package.

The rough equivalent to the snippet you shared would look like the following for Tables:

```cs
// Construct a new TableClient using a TokenCredential.
var client = new TableClient(
    new Uri(storageUri),
    tableName,
    new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Create the table if it doesn't already exist to verify we've successfully authenticated.
await client.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

More information can be found in the [Azure Tables authorization sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/samples/Sample0Auth.md) and the [Azure.Identity library overvivew](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme).

Comment: this is really helpful, I was using the Azure.Cosmos.. namespace one